# Non intrusive way to exit a method under a given condition?

Tags: java

Given this method:

```
public void walk( String path ,  ArrayList<String> files, String ext)
```

which collects all files into the `ArrayList<> files` starting at `path` and with given extension `ext`, I'm looking for a way to stop the search when a certain condition is met. For example, it should stop when `files.size()` becomes greater than a given number. How could I do this without modifying the method `walk()` ?

By not modifying the method, I mean not touching the source code in the editor. It's in a state that I like, and I don't want to touch it, because it's just for testing purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by without modifying ?

Comment: I mean: Neither the signature  nor the implementation should be changed.

Comment: sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, yes, it is

Comment: An easy approach would be to interrupt the power supply of the computer running the `walk` method.

Comment: @bigdestroyer ready to upvote your answer. Please goahead and answer.

Comment: "How could I do this without modifying the method `walk()`?" - Since you tagged it as "java": You can't.

Comment: You could potentially do it without modifying the *source code* by running a *byte code* modifier (possibly automated, at execution time). But that's still modifying the method.

Comment: "It's in a state that I like, and I don't want to touch it". So you **can** modify the code, but you don't want to, because you think it's in a perfect state?

Comment: You might consider using Java 8 streams to limit the max number of files in an elegant way, but not without changing the implementation of the method.

Comment: @alecail Is there a really good reason that you can't modify the signature to use `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`? There would actually be a decent solution for this question then.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, in order to explore various solutions to solve the same kind of problem. And please stop XY probleming me.

Comment: @alecail We've met before, have we? So you have a habit of asking badly worded questions. Are you trying to gather some sort of unholy Programmer's Bible, or do you think that the quality of questions on SO is too high as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your class extending ArrayList and override add method:

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList<String> {

        @Override
        public boolean add(String item) {
            boolean added = super.add(item);
            if (added && size() >= 10) {
                throw MaxItemsReachedException();
            }
        }

    }
```

When size is greater or equals to 10, for instance, you can throw an exception.

And call your method with an instance of MyList instead of ArrayList:

```
MyList list = new MyList();
walk("path", list, "extension");
```

Comment: @alecail If you do this even if you are able to modify the method, you're on a good track to become a bad programmer.

Comment: Then, which is the right answer: "no, you can't"? I don't know about his program's logic or why he has to do what is asking for, I have just answered his question.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your comment, but you actually don't know why I ultimately want to know how to do this.

Comment: @alecail No I don't, but there's probably a better way that you don't know. So instead of asking how you can get your horrible solution to work, you should ask the question you want to be answered. This is most likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER:  This is bad programming practice.  Dont't do this.  I only offer it because it solves the OP's problem.

Subclass ArrayList.  Add some logic to the `add` methods that throw an exception if `files.size` is greater than some threshold.

It will look like this

```
public void add(E element){
      if(size()<THRESHOLD){
           super.add(element);
      }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("STOP HERE");
      }
}
```

Try to throw an exception that `walk` does not catch and you should catch this exception in the method that calls `walk`.

Among other bad things this is using exceptions to manage flow control.